# Create file using wildcard in absolute path

Tags: files, directory, wildcards

I'm trying to use regular expression within an absolute path. For example

```
mkdir /root/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/test
```

The folder name that ends with .default is dynamically generated, but it always ends with .default. I tried *.default but it does not work.

Is there anyway to use regex in absolute paths?

Comment: What do you intend to happen? Usually a glob or regex is for matching *existing* content,  not creating new folders (mkdir)

Comment: since I don't know the name of the folder that ends with .default. I want it to match the name and construct the path

Comment: Is there one folder along the way that matches the glob *.default, and you want to create a subdirectory there named test?

Comment: correct, one folder that ends with .default and I want to create a sub-directory named test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mkdir /root/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/test
```

This will not match anything if the `test` directory does not already exist (so either `mkdir` will see a path with the asterisk, and probably error, or the shell will do something else with the failed glob, depending on the settings.)

To match an existing directory and create another inside it, you'd need to do something like these:

```
(cd /root/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/ && mkdir test)
```

or

```
for d in /root/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/ ; do 
    mkdir "$d"/test
done
```

The first assumes there is only one directory the glob matches. If there are more, the result depends on the shell and its version. The second should create the `test` directory in all directories matching the glob.

Answer (score -1):

If I am correct, this command will do it:

`mkdir "$(ls -d /root/.mozilla/firefox/*.default)"/test`

Comment: Or the other way around: If this will do it, I'm correct. However, it's unclear what it is that it will do. Consider what should happen if the pattern matches multiple names. Consider what should happen if it matches nothing.

Comment: This is for the case in which user is confident that there is only one directory matching the pattern.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, please note that in the end, replacing the explicit wildcard-resolution result of @ilkkachu's answer by the output of an `ls` of the same wildcard-resolution result adds nothing new to the existing answer, which unfortunately makes this post redundant.